# Loops is not outputting every round

Tags: javascript

My goal is to have this code go through a loop and output all the data in the array.

Having trouble getting this loops to output the entire array. I think it is overwriting the output element instead of creating a new one. My expectation is for the `para.textContent = CD[i];` to create a new

element and output each string in the array. There are ten strings, so I should be expecting ten outputs.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

```
const CD = ['BlastOff!', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Let the Count Down Begin!!!'];
const div = document.querySelector('#output');
const para = document.createElement('p');
div.appendChild(para);
console.log(para);


for (let i = CD.length; i != 0; i--) {
    if (i != 0) {

        para.textContent = CD[i];
        console.log(para);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div id="output"></div>



    <script src='java.js'></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is **eleven** strings in `CD` **not ten**, and your loop can't never show the first value (  `BlastOff!` )

Comment: maybe you whant to see my second answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating only one paragraph tag and overwriting it's value each iteration of the loop.

in order achieve what you want you need to create a new paragraph for each array item inside the loop like so

```
const CD = ['BlastOff!', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Let the Count Down Begin!!!'];
const div = document.querySelector('#output');

for (let i = CD.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    const para = document.createElement('p');
    para.textContent = CD[i];
    div.appendChild(para);
    console.log(para);
}
```

and there's no need to check again if i !== 0 inside the loop.

Comment: your loop is wrong, so this code is false.... did you ever test it  ?

Comment: Just missing > in the loop definition, but it's not wrong.

Comment: I just said, it was missing > in the loop definition so instead of the original != it would be >= 0.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mister Jojo. I am teaching myself so I tried to test in the best way that I know how. The next Project that I will be working on in my curriculum is how to do that very thing. Thank you for helping me! :)

Comment: @coe in this case you should have chosen my way of doing this loop; ...any value greater than zero is true

Comment: @Mister JoJo - Interesting; I just used it. Your answer was correct also and does seem to be more efficient.  I just started learning loops and read that I needed a condition after the counter. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @coe while having a condition isn't required in javascript, but it is a bad practice, and if you just started to learn then you should stick with the condition because not all programming languages support that.

Comment: @coe, the second argument can be a condition, but js interpreter do a boolean evaluation on it -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/valueOf

Comment: I know but it's a bad practice, because you will learn more languages in the future and you should stick with the full loop definition, don't use a shortcut.
Other languages will not support that shortcut, plus if someone is reading your code and don't know javascript it will be confusing for them.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you forget to create a new paragraph for each value ?

```js
const CD = [ 'BlastOff!', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Let the Count Down Begin!!!' ];
const div = document.querySelector('#output');

for (let i = CD.length; i--;)
  {
  let newP = document.createElement('p');
  newP.textContent  = CD[i];
  div.appendChild(newP);
  }
```

```html
 <div id="output"></div>
```

Or you want to show a "real" countdown ?
in this case you have to use a setInterval:

```js
const CD   = ['BlastOff!', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Let the Count Down Begin!!!']
  ,   div  = document.querySelector('#output')
  ,   para = document.createElement('p')
  ;
let xCD = CD.length
  ;
div.appendChild(para)
para.textContent = CD[--xCD]

let intervRef = setInterval(() =>
  {
  para.textContent = CD[--xCD]
  if (!xCD) clearInterval(intervRef)
  }
  , 800);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The index of the last element in the list is `CD.length - 1`. And the index of the first one is `0`. Therefore you're loop is shifted by one and you miss the first item (and also try to access an invalid index).